# "Invalid IdP response/credential" error using signInWithPopup with Google, Facebook, or Twitter providers and Firebase Emulators Suite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

My React web app can sign-in using the Google, Facebook & Twitter providers when connecting to production; however, I'm trying to use the Firebase Emulators Suite and upon signing-in using any of the providers, I get an `auth/internal-error` error.

```js
error.message: Invalid IdP response/credential: https://my-fake-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?state=XXX&code=YYY&scope=ZZZ&authuser=2&prompt=none
```

The code is:

```js
firebase.auth().useEmulator(`http://localhost:9099`);
...
const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

I can confirm `http://localhost:9099` is a registered Authorized JavaScript origins in the Client ID for Web application settings on Google Cloud Platform.

Has anyone successfully signed-in using any of the social-media-authentications to the Firebase Authentication Emulator?